# Upper and Lower Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $\alpha∈R, n≥2$, and let be $A∈\textbf{X}_\textbf{n}\textbf{(R)}$ be a matrix satisfying the equation $$A^n+\frac{1}{4} α^2 A^{(n-2)}=αA^{(n-1)}$$ Prove that $A$ is similar to an upper triangular matrix and lower triangular matrix.

Thank you.

Comment: Please try formatting your question with TeX as in https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation it will make it far more readable.

Comment: I would start by factorising and after cancelling the A to n-2 you can solve as a quadratic